# Python: How to run tests made with unittest

Tags: python, command-line, python-unittest

This is the structure of my project, and I would like to run the test that I have made from the command line.

[image]

I am using the following command:

```
python test_hotel.py
```

However I am getting the following error

```
ImportError: No module named 'hotel'
```

What can I do to solve this problem, and is there a way to execute the whole tests in a project from the command line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running unittest from commandline, you should use this command:

```
python -m unittest tests.test_hotel
```

You need to make sure that you have followed the rules in writing unittests (https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)

Comment: What if I want to run all tests in the directory tests?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a direct way of doing that, but for that purpose, I would write another script which calls the unit test for each of the test scripts. It could be a simple bash script.

Comment: I have added an answer to run all test in the tests directory.

Answer (score 1):

As @shahram kalantari said to run a tests the command line is:

```
python -m unittest tests.test_hotel
```

If one wants to run the whole tests the command line is:

```
python -m unittest discover tests
```

If you want more information about what tests were run the `-v` flag should be included:

```
python -m unittest discover tests -v
```